# Fill angularjs ui-select from server any time dropped it down

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I use ui-select angularjs, like this :

```
<ui-select ng-model="selectedRow.selected" >
 <ui-select-match  >
 <span ng-bind="$select.selected.Name"></span>
  </ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="item in (Rows | filter: $select.search) track by item.ID">
<span ng-bind="item.Name"></span>
</ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

I am going to fill it from server when ui-select is dropped-down, I have used ng-click, but it fires two times , once drop down and once select an item. I want fill it just each time dropped it down, How can resolve this issue?